# Luces led en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

He buscado en foros pero no he dado con la respuesta.

Quisiera saber como hacer funcionar los led de mi pc en ubuntu. 
Por ejemplo al presionar el boton de wifi, que se desconecte y se apague la luz de ese boton y que se prenda al activarlo. 
Lo mismo al presionar el boton de mute.

El teclado iluminado funciona, tambien la tecla de bloq.

Agradeceria cualquier indicacion al respecto.

Comment: ¿Lo estás haciendo programáticamente, qué lenguaje de programación estás usando? En mi opinión no parece un problema de programación y [es.so] no es un foro de informática. Puedes preguntar en [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) que es el sitio de la red SE dedicado a este sistema operativo.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es una pregunta relacionada con programación.